# Was Barbara Kean always intended to be like this?

Tags: character, gotham

In Gotham season 2, it was shown that

> Barbara Kean's character has been going through a different path. Seems like a Harley Quinn-ish.

Was that always intended to be like this from the beginning or was it changed later on, due to the bad reception of her character or not getting access to a few characters?